# ASP.NET MVC: Strange typecasing error 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

Strange typecasting error: System.string -> weekmenu.SimpleTable

## Controller

```
Function Index() As ActionResult

    ViewData("ListFrontName") = WeekMenuRepository.ListFrontName()
    ViewData("ListLastName") = WeekMenuRepository.ListLastName()
    Return View()

End Function
```

## WeekMenuRepository

```
Public Function ListFrontName() Implements IWeekMenuRepository.ListFrontName

    Dim jow = From p In SimpleTable.SimpleTable Select p
    Return jow

End Function
```

## View

```
<%  For Each item As SimpleTable In ViewData("ListFrontName")%>

<p><%=item.SimpleName%></p>

<%Next%>
```

When i run this i get things to work as expected (i get a list of frontnames)

However if i change this in WeekMenuRepository i get an typecasting error, why is this, what am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

## WeekMenuRepository (changed)

=> Added: select p.SimpleName

```
Public Function ListFrontName() Implements IWeekMenuRepository.ListFrontName

    Dim jow = From p In SimpleTable.SimpleTable Select p.SimpleName
    Return jow

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the second case `ViewData("ListFrontName")` is no longer `IEnumerable<WhateverTheTypeOfSimpleTable>` but `IEnumerable<string>`

To fix this change your loop in the view:

```
<%  For Each item As String In ViewData("ListFrontName")%>
    <p><%=item%></p>
<%Next%>
```

Answer (score 0):

After your change, you're selecting p.SimpleName explicitly instead of the entire object. You need to modify your view as follows:

```
<p><%= item %></p>
```

Comment: Damn what a stupid mistake. I'm new to OO, asp and asp mvc :p, sorry guys

Comment: No problem...it's what we're here for.